# Two bodies that are combined but retain their individual identities

Tags: single-word-requests

Am unable to recall (stroke with memory issues) a word that starts with x (if I even recall that correctly) that defines two bodies (or people or entities) that are bonded but retain their individual identities.

Comment: Is this a domain-specific question (e.g. chemistry & pertaining to chemical bonds)?

Answer (score 2):

**Conjoined** as in conjoined twins, who are connected but two people.

Does not begin with “X” though.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through Chambers on my phone for words beginning with *x* (and also [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Chambers%27s_Twentieth_Century_Dictionary_1908/X_Xyster)),

> **xenomorphic**

is the nearest I can find:

> “A textual term applied to rock minerals which do not show their
> original shape”

But the sense would seem to be the opposite of that stated in the question. I wonder whether the poster has misremembered this.

Comment: The aliens in the "Alien" movie series are called xenomorphs.

Comment: @Barmar — Why? I'm not familiar with the series.

Comment: "xeno-" is a prefix that's often used to refer to alien life in SF (e.g. xenobiology).  And I think "morph" because it goes through a dramatic metamorphosis.

Comment: @Barmar — Ok. Actually in biology xenobiotics just refers to molecules that are not found in the living organism in question, e.g. toxic environmental substances. Mammals have a system of proteins (P450s) for dealing with them.

Comment: The "xeno-" prefix more generally means "foreign" (as in "xenophobe"). But in SF it usually refers to aliens from space.

Comment: Wikipedia claims that the translation of the Greek roots literally means "strange/other shape".

Comment: 'Morph' connotes 'shape'. In linguistics, 'morphology' studies how a language's words are built up from elements (e.g. participles, tenses, plurals, etc.). In biology, 'morphology' looks at how organisms are... well... organised (arrangement and number of legs, eyes, leaves, fins, etc.). 'Meta' means 'beyond', or 'next', so 'metamorphosis' generally indicates a process in something that can transform in shape -- from organisms (e.g. insects), to greatly reworked pieces of literature.

In the 'Alien' films (and other texts) 'xenomorph' really just means 'alien creature', unlike familiar ones.

Comment: @CaptainCranium — Thank you, but I am a professional scientist and am familiar with the meaning of these Greek terms. I find it difficult to see how xenomorph "really" means 'alien creature', although I can accept that it used in that way. I had wondered whether they had some distinctive foreign morphology — two heads or the like.

Comment: @David No problem! At this point I am mainly mobilising not my scientific knowledge but considerable research and lecturing experience concerning science fiction in all media, so between us we must be getting somewhere on this one.

Like all genres (and disciplines), sf generates its own lingo, and within that each text =applies= it purposefully. In the Alien franchise there is never any indication that the 'morph' element addresses the alien's lifecycle. Within Alien's Weyland-Yutani culture (all we know), the term 'xenomorph' works literally as 'foreign shape', indicating alien organisms.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can do that matches your recollection is "mixture", which admittedly does not adhere to the beginning with an "X" condition (but does satisfy the weaker condition that the word *contain* an "X").

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mixture), a mixture is

> 2: a product of mixing : COMBINATION: such as
> a: a portion of matter consisting of two or more components in varying proportions that retain their own properties
> b: a fabric woven of variously colored threads
> c: a combination of several different kinds

Importantly, this chemistry-specific definition of mixture explicitly requires the product retaining the individual properties of its component materials, as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

If a suitable x-word cannot be found, in some circumstances you could use *coalesce* and its derivatives (*coalescing*, *coalescent* and - in your case - *coalesced*...).

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coalesce)
>
> If two or more things coalesce, they come or grow together to form one thing or system.

Merriam Webster gives an example in which the components (in this case people who surely retain their individuality) coalesce into something else (a political movement):

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coalesce)
>
> formal : to come together to form one group or mass
> a group of young reformers who gradually coalesced into a political movement

Comment: How helpful it would be to the questioner if the downvoter gave reasons for their disapprobation.  Downvoting without explanation seems merely curmudgeonly and helps nobody. This site generally operates at a higher level than that.